# Combo box with submenu

Tags: combobox, submenu

[image: Combo box]

How can I show the combo box like this one, in C#.net 2010

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by combining two controls ComboBox and TreeView in one UserControl.

Although this control looks quite simple, the actual implementation isn’t clear and takes long time.
Here is the sequence of steps:

1) Custom `TreeView` and `TreeViewItem`. They provide the following functionality:
Allow to expand and  select an item from a view model (It isn’t possible to select an item of the `TreeView` using other ways)
The event which is fired when a user clicks a `TreeViewItem` (so it will be possible to close the `ComboBox`)

2) Interface for an item of the `ItemsSource` collection

```
public interface ITreeViewItemModel
{
    string SelectedValuePath { get; }
    string DisplayValuePath { get; }

    bool IsExpanded { get; set; }
    bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    IEnumerable<ITreeViewItemModel> GetHierarchy();
    IEnumerable<ITreeViewItemModel> GetChildren();
}
```

Members of this interface:

`IsExpanded` – allows to expand the `TreeViewItem` from the bound view model. Must be implemented as the `INotifyPropertyChanged` property.

`IsSelected` – allows to select the `TreeViewItem` from the bound view model. Must be implemented as the `INotifyPropertyChanged` property.

`SelectedValuePath` – the unique string (unique item id) that will be used to select and expand the treeview control.

`DisplayValuePath` – the content that will be displayed at the header when the combobox is closed

`GetHierarchy` – returns the item and its parents.

`GetChildren` – returns child items of the current item

3. Create the Combobox:

It is the most difficult part of the implementation. I was forced to create many methods to provide the connection between `Combobox` and `TreeView`. 
But although there is many private methods, there is only two public properties:

`SelectedItem` – now it is possible to get or set this item and it will be selected in the treeview.

`SelectedHierarchy` – it wasn’t necessary to create this property, but it wasn’t difficult so I’ve decided to implement it. Use list of strings instead of the actual item.

4. Add it to a view and bind with a view model:

   ```html
   <UserControl.Resources>
       <Windows:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="treeViewDataTemplate"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
       </Windows:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   </UserControl.Resources>
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
           <local:ComboBoxTreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource treeViewDataTemplate}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
   </Grid>
   ```

The `ItemTemplate` property is obligatory property and must be of the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` type.

Check this out https://vortexwolf.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/silverlight-combobox-with-treeview-inside/